# Is it normal for Outlook to take 2 weeks or more to grab AD thumbnailPhoto?

Tags: active-directory, outlook

I've been updating user images in AD over the last few weeks. For most users, that thumbnailPhoto attribute is pulled and viewed in Outlook correctly anywhere from an hour or so to 3 days after uploading the photo. For a handful, however, Outlooks sees some photos and not others even though it's been 3 weeks or longer since the photo has been uploaded.

Is it normal for it to take that long? Is there something keeping these users from seeing the photos?

I've tried manually downloading the global address list from their machine with no change.

Comment: I've done an update of AD's thumbnailPhoto attribute recently, and it certainly doesn't take that long. Though, you have to consider replication or any replication latency within your environment. In the past, I've ran an export from various DCs to ensure it picked up the update -> 
Export-RecipientDataProperty -Identity UserA -Picture | ForEach { $_.FileData | Add-Content "C:\UserAExport.jpg" -Encoding Byte}

Comment: On-premises or office 365?

Comment: @msemack - on-premise

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not normal; this is probably caused by cache issues in Outlook (which version, BTW?).

Try disabling cached mode in Outlook on the clients which have this problem, or re-creating the Outlook profile altogether.

Comment: I know one of them is Outlook 2010. I haven't perfectly identified all of the users that are having issues because they're reporting the problem with HR, who took their photo, and they're relaying it to me but I know one of them is 2010.

Comment: It's very likely to be an Outlook cache issue; try disabling cache mode and/or re-creating the Outlook profile.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's a cache issue. I went to disable cached mode and it was already disabled.